# Log in as other user having GUI capability

Tags: command-line, login, gnome-terminal, gui

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity. I log in with my usual user (admin) in graphic environment.  Once logged, I'd like to run GUI-commands like if I were another user (normal), to test a client-server application. I need several users (one for server and another for each client), because each one needs an own `$HOME` environment. In the future, they are supposed to be installed in separate machines.

So, I open a terminal and I do:

```
su - user
```

When I run any GUI command (such as 'xterm'), it tells the usual

> > No protocol specified
> >     Cannot open display:

I read several ways to solve this using `xauth`, `xhost`, etc., but the one that worked for my purposes was:

```
admin# sudo cp ~/.Xauthority ~user/. 
admin# sudo chown user ~user/.Xauthority
admin# su - user

user$ export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

Now I can run any GUI command, such as `xterm`.

However this solution, only works within same GUI session. Once you reboot computer, `.Xauthority` file changed, and this solution is no longer valid, unless I copy `.Xauthority` again, which is tedious and involves sudo commands to copy.

So, is there a way, to make it persistent within `.bashrc` or some other way? I mean, once I open a terminal from GUI and log in using `su - <user>`,  would be capable to run commands that require GUI without have to do all previous stuff.

Sorry for English.

Comment: did you try `gksu`? it has ` -l` for login and `-u` to specify a user.

Comment: HI @TmTron. Yes, but as far as know, it opens a dialog to run a command, and I don't want that. I need a terminal to compile and do some other stuff, that is able to run GUI commands (because client runs a GUI app).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local network login (ssh) instead of `su`. The option `-X` will enable forwarding of the X connection:

```
ssh -X username@localhost
```

For this to work, you must have a secure shell server (sshd) running on the host (`apt install openssh-server`). It will prompt you for a password and drop you in a shell, just like `su - username`, but with forwarding of the X Window connection. It works for remote hosts, but also locally.